# Stack navigator inside Modal - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I want to embed a stack navigator inside a Custom Modal component. Is there a way to do that with react navigation v4?
Basically I have a ModalCustomComponent, which is a filter Modal, and inside that I want to use a stack navigator to show different filter stages. I don't want to use the default react navigation modal mode but my own custom component only.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, is it possible to use stack navigator inside modal.
but for filter stages inside modal, I use this code

```
const [indexStage, setIndexStage] = useState(0)
const stages = [<FirstStage/>,<SecondStage/>,<ThirdStage/>]

return <Modal>{stages[indexStage]}</Modal>
```